# Difference between チケット, 切符 and 乗車券

Tags: meaning, usage, synonyms

チケット (chiketto) 切符 (kippu) 乗車券 (joushaken)

All words mean ticket -Is there any difference among them? When is appropriate to use them or not?

The only one thing I found yet, is that the last one means passenger ticket or train ticket in detail.

Are kippu/chiketto inappropriate in use as train ticket or are they general enough?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- チケット: Tickets for theaters, amusement parks, sport games, etc.
- 切符: Tickets in general used for trains, buses, etc.
- 乗車券: An official term used by railway companies for a type of 切符. 乗車券 refers to a [basic fare ticket](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/ticket/types.html) whose price is calculated based on the travel distance. You may additionally need other types of 切符 such as 特急券 ("limited express train ticket").

When you ride local trains, 切符 is the same as 乗車券. In everyday conversations, ordinary people usually stick to 切符 unless they need to be specific.

Comment: 切符 is also tickets for traffic violations, or figuratively "qualification" for (usually, entering) something.